# design of column inside table

Tags: sapui5

I have problem with aligning of elements

I have sap.m.Table and inside of table I have sap.m.InputListItem

```
 var tbl= new sap.m.Table({
                width: "100%",
                headerToolbar: new sap.m.Toolbar({
                    content: [
                        new sap.ui.core.Icon({
                            src : "nav-back",
                            press: this.onNavBack.bind(this)
                        })
                        , new sap.m.Title({
                            text: this.roleDetail
                        })]
                }),
                columns: [new sap.m.Column({
                    header: new sap.m.Text({
                        text: " Menu"
                    })
                }),
                    new sap.m.Column({
                        header: new sap.m.Text({
                            text: " App"
                        })
                    })
                ],
                items: [
                    fieldOfColumnItems
                ]
            });
```

in the cycle I fill this variable fieldOfColumnItems

```
fieldOfColumnItems.push(new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                    cells: [menu[i], menuItems[i]]
                }))
```

[image]

**How can I make those dropdowns to be on the right side? I want it to look nice.
Any ideas?**

Comment: `sap.m.Column` has a property `hAlign`. It will push the elements in the column to right. Is that what you need? Check:https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/1.34.9/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Column.html#getHAlign

Comment: btw: consider using xml views, they are far more readable and reusable. _Or are there any good reasons to use js-views in your case?_

Answer (score 1):

use sap.m.FlexBox:

```
...
  var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
    columns: [
      new sap.m.Column({
        header: new sap.m.Text({
          text: "Menu"
        })
      }),
      new sap.m.Column({
        header: new sap.m.Text({
          text: "App"
        })
      })
    ],
    items: [
      new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells: [
          new sap.m.FlexBox({
            justifyContent: "SpaceBetween",
            alignItems: "Center",
            items: [
              new sap.m.Label({
                text: "foo"
              }),
              new sap.m.Select({
                items: [
                  new sap.ui.core.Item({
                    text: "bar"
                  })
                ]
              }),
            ]
          })
        ]
      }),
      new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells: [
          new sap.m.FlexBox({
            justifyContent: "SpaceBetween",
            alignItems: "Center",
            items: [
              new sap.m.Label({
                text: "longerfoo"
              }),
              new sap.m.Select({
                items: [
                  new sap.ui.core.Item({
                    text: "barfits"
                  })
                ]
              }),
            ]
          })
        ]
      })
    ]
  });
...
```

[executable example](http://jsbin.com/fisokufeno/edit?html,js,output)

add on:

due to your comment:

```
fieldOfColumnItems.push(
  new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
    cells: [
      new.sap.m.FlexBox({
        justifyContent: "SpaceBetween",
        alignItems: "Center",
        items: [
          menu[i],
          menuItems[i]
        ]
      })
    ]
  })
)
```

Comment: Dont know how to apply this to my solution... tried, but without results